How to find the $n^{th}$ derivative of $\sin^{3}x\cos^{2}x$?
How to find the $n^{th}$ derivative of $\sin^{3}x\cos^{2}x$ ?
Let me explain how I tried.
Actually this question is from Higher Engineering Mathematics by B.S. Grewal.
I wrote $\sin^{3}x\cos^{2}x=\sin^{3}x(1-\sin^{2}x)$
Which implies $$\sin^{3}x\cos^{2}x=\sin^{3}x-\sin^{5}x$$
Now I tried to find the $n^{th}$ derivative of $\sin^{3}x$ first.
Therefore if $y=\sin^{3}x$, then $$y_{1}=3\sin^{2}x(\cos x)$$
Again, $$y_{2}=3(-\sin^{3}x+2\sin x\cos^{2}x)$$
But I am unable to observe any pattern for this.
Similarly I tried for $\sin^{5}x$ also.
Just kindly help me out with the pattern for this $n^{th}$ derivative.

You could try these.

Another idea would be to rewrite $\sin^3 x\cos^2 x$ as a sum of separate terms, analogous to $\cos^3 x= \frac14 \cos x+\frac34 \cos 3x$. Euler's formula is useful for finding such expansions.

Another similar option: convert everything to exponentials using $\cos x = \frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$ and similarly for sine, and work with them directly.

FYI, please see Wikipedia's Power-reduction formulae.

"But I am unable to observe any pattern for this." it is hardly anything can be observed from two steps only.

It might be helpful to use the complex exponential expansion of trig functions.
$$\sin x = \frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i}$$
$$\cos x = \frac{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}{2}$$
So, $f(x) := \sin^{3}x\cos^{2}x$
$$=\left(\frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i} \right)^3\left(\frac{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}{2} \right)^2$$
$$=\frac{(e^{ix} - e^{-ix})^3(e^{ix} + e^{-ix})^2}{-32i}$$
$$=\frac{i}{32} (e^{3ix} - 3e^{ix} + 3e^{-ix} - e^{-3ix})(e^{2ix} + 2 + e^{-2ix})$$
$$=\frac{i}{32} (e^{5ix} - e^{-5ix} + e^{-3ix} - e^{3ix} - 2e^{ix} + 2e^{-ix})$$
And then differentiation is then just a matter of applying the rule $\frac{d}{dx} e^{ax} = ae^{ax}$.  Alternatively, you can rewrite the expression in terms of trig functions.
$$f(x) = \frac{i}{32} ((e^{5ix} - e^{-5ix}) - (e^{3ix} - e^{-3ix}) - 2(e^{ix} - 2e^{-ix}))$$
$$= \frac{i}{32} (2i\sin(5x) - 2i\sin(3x) - 2(2i\sin(x)))$$
$$= \frac{1}{16} (-\sin(5x) + \sin(3x) + 2\sin(x))$$
And then go through the usual $\sin \to \cos \to -\sin \to -\cos$ cycle.
$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{16} (-5\cos(5x) + 3\cos(3x) + 2\sin(x))$$
$$f''(x) = \frac{1}{16} (25\sin(5x) - 9\sin(3x) - 2\sin(x))$$
$$f'''(x) = \frac{1}{16} (125\cos(5x) - 27\cos(3x) - 2\cos(x))$$
$$f''''(x) = \frac{1}{16} (-625\sin(5x) + 81\sin(3x) + 2\sin(x))$$
etc.

You could say that $ \frac{1}{16} (-\sin(5x) + \sin(3x) + 2\sin(x))$ is a Fourier series decomposition.

Hint: may be you can start like this:$$\sin^{3}x\cos^{2}x=\frac{1}{4}\sin x(2\sin x \cos x)^2=\frac{1}{4}\sin x \sin^2 2x = \\ \frac{1}{8}\sin x (1-\cos 4x)=\frac{1}{8}\sin x +\frac{1}{16}\sin 3x -\frac{1}{16}\sin 5x$$

For $x=\pi$ the LHS is $0$, but the RHS is not.

@jjagmath: Thanks, there was a mistake in applying product to sum formula. Should be OK now.

Decompose it into multiple angle functions that don't have the powers. A good way to do this without having to memorize multiple angle formulas is to use the trigonometric sumproduct relations. Note that these reduce to the double angle formulas when computing $\sin^2(x)$ or $\cos^2(x)$.
Thereby
$\sin^3(x)=\sin^2(x)\sin(x)=\frac12[1-\cos(2x)]\sin(x)$
$=\frac12\sin(x)-\frac12\cos(2x)\sin(x)$
$=\frac12\sin(x)-\frac14\sin(3x)+\frac14\sin(x)$
$\sin^3(x)=3\frac14\sin(x)-\frac14\sin(3x)$
And then
$\sin^3(x)\cos^2(x)=3\frac14\sin(x)\cos^2(x)-\frac14\sin(3x)\cos^2(x)$
$=\frac38\sin(x)[1+\cos(2x)]-\frac18\sin(3x)[1+\cos(2x)]$
$=\frac1{16}[6\sin(x)+3\sin(3x)-3\sin(x)-2\sin(3x)-\sin(5x)-\sin(x)]$
$\color{blue}{\sin^3(x)\cos^2(x)=\frac1{16}[-\sin(5x)+\sin(3x)+2\sin(x)]}$
We can now differentiate term by term, using easily rendered formulas for the derivatives of sines and cosines plus the chain rule. Note that even derivatives will contain sines and odd derivatives will contain cosines, so you have a different formula for each of these cases.
